# Коллекции и модели

Tags: backbone.js

Здравствуйте, уважаемые хешкодовцы!

Случился у нас большой спор между разработчиками. Решили обратиться за помощью к сообществу. Дело в том, что этот спор уже тянется очень долго. И никак разработчики не договорятся между собой. Приводит это к конфликтам большим в команде.

Прошу помочь нам решить наш спор.

1. Есть некий метод REST api, который возвращает JSON массив.
2. А вот дальше случается спор.

1 разработчик делает так. 
Создает коллекцию и работает с ответом как "набором моделей".

2 разработчик говорит, что так неверно (и тянется этот спор нескончаемо долго). 
Второй разработчик предлагает сделать fetch() с одной моделью, а потом в виде по циклу for парсить json ответ.

Доводы каждой из сторон:

**1 разработчик (работа с коллекцией)**:

> С сервера получается массив ПОЛНОСТЬЮ
> однотипных объектов. Эти объекты
> вполне могут быть обработаны
> коллекцией. Нет смысла переживать из
> за 2х кб оперативной памяти, если это
> позволит иметь крассивый код.

**2 разработчик (ручной перебор JSON "без использования коллекции")**:

> Когда с сервера получаетса массив
> данных, этот массив "вручную"
> перебирается в коллекции. Это ведет к
> издержкам, и большым.

**При всем при этом ни одна из сторон не может предоставить замеры скорости так называемых "издержек"**.

В контексте описанного выше 2-й разработчик формирует вопрос таким образом:

> В каких именно случаях нужно
> использовать 
> модели, а в каких лучше использовать
> коллекции?
>
> Если, например, с сервера возвращается
> массив однотипных данных, и нужно
> просто вывести в вид этот массив, нужно
> ли использовать колекция или лучше
> использовать модель?
>
> Может, еще навести примеры, когда
> правильно использовать модель, а когда
> коллекцию?
>
> Всех зарание благодарю.

Comment: @BlackWidow, пара строк кода не помешала бы пониманию проблемы.

Comment: > При всем при этом ни одна из сторон не может предоставить замеры скорости так называемых "издержек".

Вот спор со мной на этом месте бы закончился. Даже не дойдя до того, что обсуждается экономия на спичках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант более верен ИМХО.

Зачем еще обрабатывать данные, если данные уже приходят с сервера и сразу заливаются в коллекцию. Во втором варианте вы убираете работу бекбона и ручками это делаете. Можно и гвоздь микроскопом забить, но зачем?